# text processing in python to remove hex color codes from string

Tags: python, html, regex, hex

I have a pandas dataframe with a column of text and i want to remove the html color codes from there, here is an example of the text:

```
{color:#000000}So today while lurking around with the processing, I have stumbled across the main reason why it takes 15 minutes. {color}{color:#000000} {color}{color:#000000}It is because our trigger tooks 15 minutes to finishing sending the signal!{color}{color:#000000} {color}{color:#000000}
```

My desired output does not have those hex colors

```
So today while lurking around with the processing, I have stumbled across the main reason why it takes 15 minutes.It is because our trigger tooks 15 minutes to finishing sending the signal
```

Comment: This: `!?{color}|!?{color:#\d{2,6}}` https://regex101.com/r/5CnaPo/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
re.sub(r'\{color.*?\}', '', st)

st = "{color:#000000}So today while lurking around with the processing, I have stumbled across the main reason why it takes 15 minutes. {color}{color:#000000} {color}{color:#000000}It is because our trigger tooks 15 minutes to finishing sending the signal!{color}{color:#000000} {color}{color:#000000}"
```

---

```
re.sub(r'\{color.*?\}', '', st)
```

---

**Output:**

```
'So today while lurking around with the processing, I have stumbled across the main reason why it takes 15 minutes.  It is because our trigger tooks 15 minutes to finishing sending the signal! '
```